# PHP if-statements for joomla positions using Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, conditional-statements

I am building a Joomla template based on Master Bootstrap for Joomla! 3.x http://www.masterbootstrap.com/ It incorporates Bootstrap 3 into this Joomla Template.

I have built a row in which I want to have the possibility to use 6, 4, 3, 2 or 1 Joomla positions with widths of 2, 3, 4, 6 or 12 columns respectively, the way you do in Bootstrap (BS). FYI: I want to be flexible with the number of icons I put in those positions with a maximum of 6 icons, a module position for each icon.

In the past I have made PHP if-statements for this with only 2 or 3 positions with widths of 6 or 4 BS columns respectively. That was relatively easy as you are limited in the number of columns to use.

Now I started to build if-statements for the first column, let's call it 'column-a' and that was a 172 lines. Doing this for a larger number of columns I would come up an enormous amount of code. So I was wondering if I could do this easier, still using PHP if statements, so I remain flexible in the use of columns or positions and being able to use bootstrap to make a responsive website. 
Here's the code. I am a beginner at PHP, so if you have suggestions or solutions, please spell it out, so that a fledgeling can understand:

```
    <!-- php if statements column-a -->
<?php if  ($this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c') && $this->countModules('column-d') && $this->countModules('column-e') && $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if zes modules, then 2-column modules -->

<div name="column-a-2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
<!-- end 2 column --> 
<!-- 3-column modules -->
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b c d, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b c e, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b c f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b d e, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b d f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b e f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c d e, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c d f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c e f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a d e f, then 3-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<!-- end 3-column modules --> 
<!-- 4-column modules -->
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b c, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b d, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b e, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a b f, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c d, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c e, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a c f, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a d e, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a d f, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a e f, then 4-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-4" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<!-- end 4-column modules --> 
<!-- 6-column modules -->
<?php elseif ($this->countModules('column-b') && !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a en b, then 6-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b')&& $this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a en c, then 6-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b')&& !$this->countModules('column-c')&& $this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a en d, then 6-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b')&& !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& $this->countModules('column-e')&& !$this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a en e, then 6-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<?php elseif (!$this->countModules('column-b')&& !$this->countModules('column-c')&& !$this->countModules('column-d')&& !$this->countModules('column-e')&& $this->countModules('column-f')) : ?>
<!-- if modules a en f, then 6-column modules -->
<div name="column-a-6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<!-- end 6-column modules --> 
<!-- 12-column modules -->
<?php else : ?>
<div name="column-a-12" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="column-a" style="html5" />
</div>
<!-- end 12-column modules --> 
<!-- end php if statements column-a -->
```

Thanx

Thom

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: probably a good idea. :-)